# ASMX Webservice Test tool

Tags: c#, web-services

Is there any simple tool to test ASMX webservices where I can provide the service URL, request XML and get back the result (xml stream in my case)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org) is a very comprehensive web test tool. Also you can look at firefox extension [SOA Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/soa-client/).

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days you could just visith the asmx url to get a simple IIS wrapper around the webservice as long as you are using primitive data-types in the functions.

Generating a winform application (or webform) that calls the webservice takes less about as much time as starting vs.net, why not just create a little test harness that way.